# Zigbee Redundant RF

Tags: zigbee

What does **Redundant RF** means in general?

And how can I tell if my **Zigbee** module has redundant RF feature

and if there is, how would I know the available **number of redundant RF** does it have?

Comment: Where does the quote come from - post a link or a picture but name your source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an extra channel that Zigbee can use from its bandwidth. WiFi and bluetooth also operates on the same frequency. So that if working link is busy or having much power because of wifi or bluetooth this redundant RF link will be used and data transferred on to that frequency

[image]

It has total 16 channels from which 12 channels are multiplexed with WiFi and remaining can be used.